# Call to EJB method from a remote jboss server(servlet)

Tags: servlets, jboss, ejb, message-driven-bean

case 1:
I'm having war in one jboss server and ejb jar in another jboss server.
I want to call my ejb from my servlet which is present in another server. 
How to call it. can any one help me with a working sample and required configurations.

case 2:
Message Driven Bean(MDB) in my transaction jboss server and business method in another jboss server. How to call my business method from my transaction server.

kindly help me to solve this case

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google's first hit after entering `jboss`, `remote`, `ejb`: http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=30166

Answer (score 2):

I can't (won't) help with a working example, but this is what you have to do:

1. Your EJBs (session beans) must be configured in a way to support remote access, RMI.
2. You have to export your EJB client classes into a separate JAR file; those are the interfaces and base classes required to perform an RMI call (stubs). This is required as clients (your WAR) must understand how to deserialize/serialize the RMI communication between your servlets and the remote EJBs.
3. Make the exported EJB client JAR available to your WAR file
4. Define an initial context pointing to your remote EJB server as described [here](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=30166).
5. Deploy and run it...

BTW: A personal opinion, RMI communication is painful and you should try to avoid it as it tightly couples the client (your WAR) to the remote EJBs.

EDIT: Which EJB version and which IDE do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll check this. I'm using EJB2.1 and Netbeans IDE